# PHP/MySQL Job queueing system doing jobs more than once

Tags: php, mysql, cron, rabbitmq, zeromq

I came up with a very simple job queueing system using PHP, MySQL and cron.

1. Cron will call a website, which has a function that calls function `A()` every 2 seconds. `A()` searches and retrieves a row from table `A`
2. Upon retrieving a row, `A()` will update that row with value `1` in column `working`
3. `A()` then does something to the data in the retrieved row
4. `A()` then insert a row in table `B` with the value obtained during processing step `3`.

**Problem:** I notice that there are sometimes duplicate values in the table `B` due to function `A()` retrieving the same row from table `A` multiple times.

Which part of the design above is allowing the duplicate processing, and how should it be fixed?

*Please don't suggest something like rabbitMQ without at least showing how it can be implemented in more details. I read some of their docs and did not understand how to implement it. Thanks!*

**Update:** I have a cron job that calls a page (which calls function `c()`) every minute. This function `c()` that does a loop 30 times which calls function `A()`, using `sleep()` to delay.

Comment: What happens if your first query takes more than 2 seconds to run? Is there any kind of lock to make sure that you don't get two queries running at the same time?

Comment: my approach will be.... at the beginning of script i will check if the  previous script from cron is still running or not... if running then dont run this if not then continue

Comment: nitpick: cron doesn't call "functions". It executes programs/scripts at specified times.

Comment: I have a cron job that calls a page (which calls function `c()`) every minute. This function `c()` that does a loop 30 times which calls function `A()`, using `sleep()` to delay.

Comment: @Surace The script from cron calls this function 30 times a minute. So there is really only 1 script running at a time.

Comment: @Nyxynyx - if your SELECT takes 1 second to run, and you're sleeping for 2 seconds, then each call to `c()` will take 90 seconds to complete.

Comment: @andrewsi So the previous cron job may overlap with the next cron job? I notice some jobs done 4 times too. Most jobs take about 5 seconds to run. Will the problem be solved by (somehow) running `function A()` asynchronously if that is possible?

Comment: @Nyxynyx - you just need to add some locking to the code, so if the code is already running, it doesn't start off again.

Comment: thats what i am saying before you start processing check if the script is already running if it is then dont start the script if not then start processing

Comment: @andrewsi How would I implement this locking? I just came across MySQL's `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` for a locking row read, would that help?

Comment: @Surace I get it now. In this case, if the previous cron job took 61 second, the next cron job would notice the previous cron job running, and just quit, then nothing will be done for this 59 second of the 2nd minute.

Comment: @Nyxynyx - I don't know how mysql does it; I've always used `flock()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: I agree with @andrewsi flock() is awesome for this. I use it for a distributed video encoder, havent had lapping problems yet. But be sure to use it with the `LOCK_EX` option

Comment: i have done it using sh ... i do pgrep and if process is found then dont do anything if not kick the php script which does the job

Comment: Thanks for introducing `flock()`. Would `flock()` be used on a file say `lock.txt`, then the page called by cron would get try to get a lock on that file before running, otherwise it will quit, this way preventing overlapping cron jobs?

Comment: Great, that solves the overlapping cron problem, hopefully that will get rid of the duplicate processing. If I understand correctly, function `A()` will sleep after it has done its processing, which means only 1 function `A()` can be running at a time. If I want to scale up, if there a way to call a new function `A()` every second and let it run before the previous call to `A()` has finished proecssing?

Comment: I know your gonna ahte me for saying this but an MQ? :P It doesn't need to be rabbitMQ you can make your own distributor in like 100 lines.

Comment: Ahh... I will try using `flog()` and some mysql row locking and see how it goes. Maybe if row locking works, I do not have to worry about overlapping cron jobs :) Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem could be the processing at first:

> Cron will call a function A() that searches and retrieves a row from table A every 2 seconds.

The processing of this part of the script could take longer than two seconds on a table without indexes as such you could pick multiple rows.

You could remedy this with an exclusive file lock.

I have a feeling there is more than just the workflow, if you can show some basic code attached maybe there might be a problem in the code as well.

#### edit

I think it is timing judging by your last update:

> Update: I have a cron job that calls a page (which calls function c())
>   every minute. This function c() that does a loop 30 times which calls
>   function A(), using sleep() to delay.

Thats a lot of jumping through hoops and I think you might have a threading problem where crons are overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

The supplied answer is good, file locks work well, but, since you're using MySQL, I thought I'd answer as well. With MySQL you can implement cooperative asynchronous locking using [GET_LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and [RELEASE_LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock).

> *DISCLAIMER: The examples below are untested. I have successfully implemented something very close to this before, and the below was the general idea.

Let's say you've wrapped this GET_LOCK function in a PHP class called Mutex:

```
class Mutex {
  private $_db = null;
  private $_resource = '';

  public function __construct($resource, Zend_Db_Adapter $db) {
    $this->resource = $resource;
    $this->_db      = $db;
  }

  // gets a lock for $this->_resource; you could add a $timeout value,
  // to pass as a 2nd parameter to GET_LOCK, but I'm leaving that
  // out for now
  public function getLock() {
    return (bool)$this->_db->fetchOne(
      'SELECT GET_LOCK(:resource)',
      array(
        ':resource' => $this->_resource
      ));
  }

  public function releaseLock($resource) {
    // using DO because I really don't care if this succeeds; 
    // when the PHP process terminates, the lock is released
    // so there is no worry about deadlock
    $this->_db->query(
      'DO RELEASE_LOCK(:resource)',
      array(
        ':resource' => $resource
      ));
  }
}
```

Before A() fetches methods from the table, have it ask for a lock. You can use any string as the resource name.

```
class JobA {
  public function __construct(Zend_Db_Adapter $db) {
    $this->_db = $db;
  }

  public function A() {
    // I'm assuming A() is a class method and that the class somehow
    // acquired access to a MySQL database - pretend $this->db is a 
    // Zend_Db instance. The resource name can be an arbitrary 
    // string - I chose the class name in this case but it could be 
    // 'barglefarglenarg' or something.
    $mutex = new Mutex($this->db, get_class($this));

    // I choose to throw an exception but you could just as easily 
    // die silently and get out of the way for the next process, 
    // which often works better depending on the job
    if (!$mutex->getLock())
      throw new Exception('Unable to obtain lock.');

    // Got a lock, now select the rows you need without fear of 
    // any other process running A() getting the same rows as this
    // process - presumably you would update/flag the row so that the
    // next A() process will not select the same row when it finally
    // gets a lock. Once we have our data we release the lock

    $mutex->releaseLock();

    // Now we do whatever we need to do with the rows we selected
    // while we had the lock
  }
}
```

When you engineer a scenario in which multiple processes are selecting and modifying the same data, this kind of thing comes in very handy. When using MySQL, I prefer this database approach to the file locking mechanism, for portability - it's easier to host your app on different platforms if the locking mechanism is external to the filesystem. Sure it can be done, and it works fine, but in my personal experience I found this easier to use.

If you plan on your app being portable across database engines, then this approach will probably not work for you.